# How to set margin at bottom of label?

Tags: codenameone

I try to set margin on bottom of label by following code but margin is adding at top instead of bottom , am I doing anything wrong? I have also try using top margin and its also showing same as shown in image[image]

```
  Label labelIcon = findLabelIconAccount(form);
  **labelIcon.getStyle().setMargin(Component.BOTTOM, 50);**
  //labelIcon.getStyle().setMargin(Component.TOP, 50);
  labelIcon.setIcon(image);
```

Comment: can you put your xml relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

What's the layout hierarchy?

Setting the margin at the bottom might increase allocated space to the layout and result in the whole layout changing I suggest setting the margin to the parent of that label as it seems you want to push the whole UI higher and not just the label.